# Bash For Loop: Decrementing starting from a variable

Tags: bash

I've done some searching and this looks like it should work, and it isn't, and I'm stumped.

I'm on a CentOS box and want to basically shift all backups 1 folder up, to a limit of like 60 backups, and that limit is set in a variable $BKPLIMIT.

```
for (( i=$BKPLIMIT; i==0; i-- )); do
    j=$(($i-1))
    if [ -d "backup.$j" ]; then
        echo "$i $j backup.$i backup.$j"
        #mv "backup.$j" "backup.$i"
    fi
done
```

It looks, from my debugging, the script is not entering the loop.  I is stumped :( I've also tried doing "$(seq $BKPLIMIT 0) which didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Change `i==0` to `i>0` or `i!=0`.   The loop condition must be true for the loop to be executed.

Comment: DUrr...I was treating it as an "until" not a "while" I'm an idiot.  Thanks.